# UIImage orientation issues when retrieved from ALAssset

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i choose photo that taken in portrait mode the ALAsset give me it in landscape mode, and i found a lot of rotate methods and non of them was really rotate the UIImage .

this is how i take the UIImage:

```
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]]
```

can any one did stuck with this problem too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone have the same problem he can use the method in this url :
http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2009/03/30/iphone-uiimage-rotation-and-mirroring/